# upsert data for a list of objects to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Often times, I find myself needing to send a user updated collection of records to a stored procedure. For example, lets say there is a contacts table in the database. On the front end, I display lets say 10 contact records for the user to edit. User makes his changes and hits save.

At that point, I can either call my upsertContact stored procedure 10 times with the user modified data in a loop, or send an XML formatted `<contact><firstname>name</firstname><lastname>lname</lastname></contact>` with all 10 together to the stored procedure. I always end up doing xml.

Is there any better way to accomplish this. Is the xml method going to break if there are large number of records due to size. If so, how do people achieve this kind of functionality?

FYI, it is usually not just a direct table update so I have not looked into sqldatasource.

Change: Based on the request, the version so far has been SQL 2005, but we are upgrading to 2008 now. So, any new features are welcome. Thanks.

**Update** : based on [this](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html) article and the feedback below, i think Table Valued Parameters are the best approach to choose. Also the new [merge](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/merge-statement-with-table-valued-parameters.aspx) functionality of sql 2008 is really cool with TVP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of SQL Server? You can use table-valued parameters in SQL Server 2008+ ... they are very powerful even though they are read-only and are going to be less hassle than XML and less trouble than converting to ORM (IMHO). Hit up the following resources:

MSDN : Table-Valued Parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Erland Sommarskog's Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008 / Table-Valued Parameters:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#TVP_in_TSQL

Comment: i have used table variables within a sql stored proc, but not passing in from code. Do you know what will be the data type in c# for this and how that will be populated.

Comment: If you look further down in Erland's article, he has some thoughts around using a List, a DataTable and even a DataReader. http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#ADONET

Comment: That looks very promising. Thanks for that. Let me play with it a little bit and see.

Answer (score 0):

I would think directly manipulating XML in the database would be more trouble than it is worth to go that route; I would suggest instead making each call separate like you suggest; 10 calls to save each contact.

There are benefits to that approach and drawbacks; obviously, you're having to create the database connection. However, you could simply queue up a bunch of commands to send on one connection.

Comment: For 10 records, it may be fine to call them one at a time, but what about a 100? what problems do you envision with the xml route?

Comment: XML can get very expensive to parse. While SQL Server has come a long way in its XML support, it's a long ways from perfect or even what I'd call "optimal."

Comment: It may be more optimal than calling the proc multiple times, just a thought.

Comment: If those are the only two options, sure; but I think there are better options (e.g. TVP). We encountered this same debate at my old company - should we allow stored procedures that take in multiple rows, or should we make the API make multiple calls? You might not come to the same conclusion but mine would be, in order of preference, TVP, then XML, then making multiple calls. If I couldn't do TVP I would take XML but I wouldn't be ecstatic about it.

Comment: Great point, if TVP works for List<Contact> objects, its really great. Although, i'm wondering if it can handle a list<address> inside a single contact object. XML can.

Comment: You might have to send a List of contacts and a List of addresses with some way for the stored procedure to join the two TVPs (I assume there is some relationship there you can already borrow from).

Comment: Not trying to nitpick, but some of the contacts could be new and there is no real easy way to tie them to the address records if address is a separate TVP.

Comment: So you are creating new contacts and modifying existing contacts within the same form? Ok, so can't you have a code for each contact that says new or not? And then can't your form give each new contact a sequence number (tied to both the new contact and its associated addresses)? This doesn't sound like a problem with TVPs per se. This is essentially what you need to do if you build XML too - you have to nest it the right way, in the right order, for the recipient to know what to do with it.

Comment: You could also just have a single TVP that stored the contact information redundantly, with a row for each address. You'd still be able to identify which ones are new and just group by that to determine the rest of the information. Lots of approaches here and again none of the problems you mention seem to exist solely with TVPs, they just have different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The Sql Server XML datatype is the same as a VARCHAR(MAX) so it would take a really large changeset to cause it to break.

I have used a similar method in the past when saving XML requests and responses and found no issues with it.  Not sure if it's the "best" solution, but "best" is always relative.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use an [Object-Relational-Management(ORM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) solution like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) or [the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  These solutions provide you with the ability to make changes to objects, and have the changes propagated to the database by the ORM provider.  This makes them much more flexible than issuing your own sql statements to the database.  They also make optimizations like sending all changes in a single transaction over a single connection.

Comment: Can you update multiple entities at the same time too? sometimes contacts can have a list of address as well. I have heard that you don't get to control the sql generated by them and in some cases, it may not be optimal.

Comment: It is true that you don't control the SQL that is generated by the requests.  However, you _can_ have your objects call stored procedures for inserts and updates if you need to modify the SQL.

Comment: Also, one call would upsert your entire object graph.  So if contacts have addresses, those would be inserted as well.